# Is there a way to change the -webkit-focus-ring-color?

Tags: css, colors, webkit, focus

How do I change the color of `-webkit-focus-ring-color`? Chrome has a light blue that clashes with my CSS, I'd like to change it to another color hex but keep the rest of the style (faded edge, width) the same.

Also, is there an important reason this is a bad idea? Thanks?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following css should do for Chrome (changing just the colour of the outline):

```
.thing:focus {
  outline-color: [MY_COLOUR];
}
```

If you want consistent css across browsers, you'd be better off writing your own complete style and probably also including a css reset before that.

If you're happy with the browser focus style and just want to change the colour, the above should do.  You might also want to do some quick research to see what the default focus style is for other browsers (maybe some use border?) and set those colours as well.

If you want to emulate the chrome style across all browsers, try this (from the chrome user-agent stylesheet):

```
.thing:focus {
  outline: [My_COLOUR] auto 5px;
}
```

Comment: I eventually got this to work on my site but I had to include `!important`. You're able to make it work without that flag?

Comment: In chrome v62 for OSx, yes.  It could be that prior versions of chrome set the focus style directly on the element somehow instead of through the user-agent stylesheet?  That would certainly mess with the selector specificity and would necessitate the !important.

Comment: The `outline` shorthand property functions like the one for `border`: if you override the shorthand, you need to account for all properties you are overriding. You can't cherrypick just color. `outline: red auto 5px` would be valid whereas `outline: red` won't work.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/jmysiak/fpqp1zv3/2/

```
input {
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.15s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.15s;
      -o-transition: all ease-in-out 0.15s;}

input:focus { 
  outline: none;
  border-color: #df9eed;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #df9eed;}
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked :( You've replaced an outline with a border which means that focusing will now change the layout of your page: borders take space; outlines do not.

Comment: @DylanYoung - borders only take space if you aren't using box-sizing: border-box; Check it out. It's how all modern people write CSS.

Comment: From my understanding, that only effects height and width calculations and is generally very useful for that.  The border will still push elements to avoid overlap, if I'm not mistaken. Correct me if I'm wrong! In this case (fixed size input) with border-box will squish the contents of the input when you add a border. With content-box (fixed size input), it will push neighbouring elements around (if there isn't enough space to accommodate the border).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You just style it. It's an outline. But you should put something cool looking that still denotes focus so that people who use it, can still see where they are on the page. They might be assisted by other devices besides the standard mouse.

[a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/JL4ae/)

### HTML

```
<button class="thing">Something</button>
```

or

```
<input class="thing" type="text" />
```

### CSS

```
.thing {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.thing:focus {
    outline: 0;    
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't do at all what the OP asked: "I'd like to change it to another color hex but keep the rest of the style"